# Late night buses from Helsinki airport to Turku in December?

Tags: buses, finland, helsinki, hel

I'm traveling in December.  I arrive at Helsinki airport (HEL) at 9pm and would like to get to Turku as soon as possible.  What is the latest night bus available?  Alternatively, how early can I take one the next morning?

Comment: From a quick exploration on Google Maps it appears that buses run all night and stop at Terminal 1 and Terminal 2, though Google seems to want to tell me to walk 550m to a farther stop (not happening).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Matkahuolto.fi central bus schedule search](https://liput.matkahuolto.fi/connectionlist?lang=fi&arrivalPlaceId=p565&departurePlaceId=p611&departureDate=2015-04-27#breadcrumb), the last connection from Helsinki-Vantaa airport T2 to Turku leaves the airport at 22:50, arriving in Turku at 01:30.  (There's also an earlier bus at 21:50 which you'll likely make if your flight is on time.)  Both also serve T1 (leaving 10 minutes earlier) and involve a change of bus at Espoo's Ikea along the way, but the buses are run by the same company (*Pohjolan Liikenne*) as a guaranteed service, so this should be pretty painless.

Should you miss the 22:50, the next services are at 0:30 AM, 01:25 AM and 03:45 AM.  So you're definitely not going to get stuck at the airport for the night!

There are also other options if you detour via central Helsinki, eg. transferring to a [VR train](http://vr.fi) at Helsinki Central (last departure 23:00, but arriving slightly earlier at 01:00) and the supercheap [Onnibus](http://www.onnibus.com/fi/aikataulut.htm) service (last bus from central Helsinki at 22:45).  But if it's your first time in Helsinki and/or you're tired after a long flight etc, the direct bus is the easiest option.

Comment: i could only find the information to August 2015 - do you live nearby to know that it is the same or similar in December?   (I'm traveling on 19 December).   Awesome reply and really fast too - thanks mate, really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think they publish schedules that far in advance, but that bus service has been running through the night as long as I can remember. The exact times may change but they're not going to cancel it.

Comment: Thanks so much - really appreciate your insight jpatokal.  cheers